# Reuse MongoDB connection in Express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express.js

So I think the title is pretty straightforward. I implement a client for MongoDB and I want to include it anywhere in my app and share the connection (not create it always or close it always).

So my question is, what are the downsides of this implementation? I've noticed that if I don't explicitly call `disconnect` the app never finishes / closes. Am I doing something wrong here? What are your suggestions to increase the re-usability and quality of my code? Thanks!

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient,
    dbName = 'ppl',
    collection = 'pp',
    mongoUrl = `mongodb://ip-and-port/${dbName}`;
let db;

class Mongo {
    static connect() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, (err, database) => {
                if (err) { reject(err); }
                db = database;
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }

    static disconnect() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                db.close();
                resolve();
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        })
    }

    static insertMany(data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const col = db.collection(collection);
                col.insertMany(data, (err, returns) => {
                    resolve({
                        err,
                        results: returns.insertedCount
                    });
                });
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    }
}
```